# Dual boot modular partitioning

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning, linux-mint, boot-partition

I want to install linux mint 14 alongside my already installed windows 7; there is an install alongside windows 7 option but I don't know how that will partition my drive and I don't think it will make the swap the size I want so I would like to do it manually.

I believe my hdd is mbr and I have 2 primaries (100MB of system reserved(NTFS) and 230GB of Windows(NTFS)) and 230GB of unallocated.

I was told linux would install grub in the windows partition and boot from there so it wouldn't create another primary partition. Is this true? If so which partition?

I'm just trying to setup my hdd in a modular way so that I can put other operating systems on the disk, maybe replace my distro or have the option to boot more than 2 operating systems. I might leave some unallocated space (I'm not sure why though, I guess only if I was booting something other than linux right? because I can just change the /boot to boot a different distro of linux, right?)

I'm a little confused as to the best way to do this?

1. Will mint 14 create another primary or will it just sit in my
   windows partition?
2. Do I have to make a `/boot`, or just should I?
3. What is the mount point? Is that where it will look for the boot
   loader? So would I mount at `/boot`?
4. I was thinking of making a `/boot`, `/home` and `swap`, should a `/` be
   included? If so why? What is its purpose?
5. Should I mount at `/`?
6. How large should `/` and `/boot` be?

I greatly appreciate the help.